# Connection refused between 2 Docker Containers running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: angularjs, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I've cloned my project from GitHub to my AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance and I'm attempting to Deploy/Host it using Docker containers. The frontend of my application is an Angular project that I have built out to the dist folder and I intend to use Nginx to be able to view it.

The Backend of my application is a Node server thats running with Express. The problem I'm having seems to be with my Docker configuration.

When I run **docker-compose up --build -d**, I visit my ec2 IP address and the application is there and I can interact with it but when I try loading a resource from the Node Backend I get a connection refused with a Http Error Response in the Browser as shown below.

[image]

The following is my docker config files:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./Crypto-Trader
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - node
    networks:
      - local

  node:
    build: ./Server/Node
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - local

networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile for Frontend config

```
FROM nginx

COPY ./dist/Crypto-Trader /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Dockerfile for Node Backend

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /src

COPY . /src

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I should also mention in my Angular project I have an environment variable for the url connection string set up like so

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  dockerIP: 'node'
};

So in my Angular services the connection string to the backend would look something like:

http://${dockerIP}:3000/someresource
```

I've tried a couple of different ways to connect to the backend by changing the dockerIP to:

**0.0.0.0** or **localhost** and neither have worked so I'm at a loss of what to do now.

In my ec2 instance I've ran the Node container separately and been able to access data by running this curl command on the command line:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/profiles/products-list
```

but whenever I run the two containers together there seems to be a communication error between them.

So I hope I've provided enough information for someone to help me out I'm not sure what else I can try for the 2 containers to communicate. Thanks in advance to anyone who replies with an answer.

Comment: Is that your local browser giving you the "not resolved" error for "node:3000" address? If that's the case - it's expected. node:3000 address is accessible only to the containers within your docker network. You might try my-ec2-instance-public-ip:3000 to get to your backend.

Comment: Yeah that's my local browser. OK yeah I understand what your saying that was just my last attempt before asking the question. Eh right now I have run my Backend as a separate container and I'm trying to access it using Postman and I've tried both the ec2 public DNS (IPv4) and the IPv4 Public IP and still not connecting.

Comment: Does your security group allow connection to port 3000 then?

Comment: No ,I didn't have it now and it's working. Thanks a lot Anton.

Comment: You are welcome! I turned these comments into the answer. Please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting from your local machine make sure:

- You are not using Docker network DNS name (`node:3000`), but EC2 instance's public IP
- Security group for your instance should allow inbound traffic on port 3000